# SQL yes/no CASE with distinct results

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to get a yes/no from an inventory DB. Each user has more than one item in inventory. I am looking for one specific item and would like a simple yes/no column. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT USER,
CASE HARDWARE_REF
WHEN 'DELL' THEN 'YES'
ELSE 'NO'
END AS DELL
FROM USER_DB
LEFT OUTER JOIN ASSETS_DB ON USER_DB.USER = ASSETS_DB.OWNER

RESULT
```

USER   DELL

```
AB1234  NO
CD3456  YES
EF4567  NO

enter code here
```

I am only wanting a single yes/no response if they have a DELL or not. My current query gives a list, but it shows multiple entries per user. I would only like one. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm really not clear on what you're starting with or what you're looking for. Have a look at this for some additional detail. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` for this:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ASSETS_DB a
                          WHERE u.UID = a.OWNER AND a.HARDWARE_REF = 'DELL'
                         )
             THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO'
        END) as has_dell
FROM USER_DB u;
```

With an index on `ASSETS_DB(OWNER, HARDWARE_REF)` this should be the fastest query for this information (it avoids an aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

You appears to want, if i understand correctly

```
SELECT u.USER,
       SUM(CASE HARDWARE_REF WHEN 'DELL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Hardware 
FROM USER_DB u -- use alise u
LEFT OUTER JOIN ASSETS_DB ast ON u.UID = ast .OWNER 
GROUP BY u.USER;
```

You can further re-express this as:

```
CASE WHEN (<SUM AGGREGATION>) >= 1 THEN 'true' else 'false' END
```

Tiny word of advice : Always use alise that can be easier read or write.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name or give an alias to the case block. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  USER,
  CASE 
    HARDWARE_REF WHEN 'DELL' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
  END AS IS_DELL
FROM USER_D
LEFT OUTER JOIN ASSETS_DB 
ON USER_DB.UID = ASSETS_DB.OWNER
```

But if you are interested in knowing just the users using Dell hardware then you should use this instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  USER
FROM USER_DB 
INNER JOIN ASSETS_DB 
ON USER_DB.UID = ASSETS_DB.OWNER
WHERE HARDWARE_REF='DELL';
```